# request.body undefined after using express bodyParser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**Edit:** i fixed it by using:

```
app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
});
```

**Original post:**

I'm trying to figure out how to handle a post with node and express and i'm completely stuck.

After some reading i noticed people saying i should use 'middleware' whatever that means and create a line `app.use(express.bodyParser());`. I assumed that after adding that i would have a `req.body` available in my post method. This isn't the case however. It console.log's into a `undefined`.

I think I don't know how to properly set this up, so here goes nothing:

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , UserProvider = require('./userprovider').UserProvider,
  qs = require('querystring');

var userProvider = new UserProvider('localhost', 27017);

var app = express(), 
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8080);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/new_game', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/new_game.html');
});


app.post('/new_game', function(req, res) {
    var codeToUse = Math.random()*10000;
    codeToUse = Math.round(codeToUse);
    console.log(req.body);
});


app.use(express.bodyParser());



app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Well I think the use of the middleware should be done at the top in your program. Their placement in your program and order matters..isn't?

Comment: I've fixed my own issue as shown above. Thanks nonetheless. While i'm at it: Can i send a variable made in my app.js to my view somehow?

Comment: Yes you can. Either you are using Jade or EJS as your template engine, it can be accomplished in both. When you use the render function then after mentioning the name of the page in the view; you can pass in the second argument your variables. Lets say you have a variable 't' in which you a string which you want to keep as the title of the page then the function call will be like this `response.render('index',{title:t});`  and then you can use 'title' in your index page to get the string value of var t.

Comment: I was trying to avoid Jade because i hate the syntax so much. Thanks any way!

Comment: @CaptainCarl there are literally dozens of different templating engines you can use with Express, no need to use Jade if you don't want to :)

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451966/express-js-body-parser-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

Though you've said now your code works, but i won't suggest you to use bodyParser in the options of

```
app.configure()
```

What it does is that, if you use it as you have done, any file can be send into your system for all post requests. It's better if you use

```
express.json()
```

and

```
express.urlencoded()
```

in the options of
    `app.configure()`,
and when you expect a file use bodyParser in the respective post route like this

```
app.post('/upload', express.bodyParser(), function(req, res){//do something with req.files})
```