# In Express.js with body-parser the value of request.body is undefined

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, httprequest

I'm having a problem I cannot diagnose.

On a server, I have a simple URL handler using Express.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');

app.configure(function() {
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(bodyParser.json()); // see: http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));
});

app.post('/submit', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

On client side, there's a form which is handled with Angular controller:

```
$scope.submit = function () {
    // $http.post('/submit', $scope.data); // POST request to send data to the server
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/submit',
        data: $scope.data
    });

    console.log('POST /submit ' + JSON.stringify($scope.data));
};
```

In browser's console everything is fine: `$scope.data` is valid; Node.js also responds with `console.log`, as expected, but writes `undefined` which means that, well, `request.body` is undefined.

What do I do wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: does the request in the network tab in the browser console have the body?

Comment: what version of express are you using?  The docs say: `All routing methods will be added in the order in which they appear. You should not do app.use(app.router). This eliminates the most common issue with Express.` https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/New-features-in-4.x

Comment: I use Express 3.2.4 and I'm completely sure `app.router` is out of scope of this question.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using **Express 3** you shouldn't have to use the **body-parser** module as it is already bundled with **Express 3** as `express.bodyParser`. You're getting an empty body because you're putting `app.use(app.router)` before the body parser.

```
app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(app.router);
});
```

Which is why your other solution is working:

```
app.post('/submit', bodyParser.json(), function (req, res) {
```

Comment: I tried putting it after, and none of URI handlers worked. Out it back, and everything was fine. However, in many other similar questions, I've seen exactly opposite advice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just came up with solution, and it works. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19900799/1287643) the `app.post` using body-parser is explained in few words. So I changed POST request handler definition to:

```
app.post('/submit', bodyParser.json(), function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

And now not only `console.log(req.body)` returns valid data, but it's deserialized into JSON correctly on the server without any extra code (which is, well, expected from Angular+Node pair).